# Validation for numbers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to make a validation on element-ui work.I have a input who can get only numbers, it's working good if i start with a number, the problem is i can add characters inside the input and every number after that character is lost on save.

```
{ required: true, message: 'Camp obligatoriu', trigger: 'change' },
{ type: 'number', pattern: '^\d+$', message: 'Valoare numerica obligatorie', trigger: 'change' },
{ type: 'number', min: 1, max: 500, message: 'Valoarea trebuie sa fie intre 1 si 500 m', trigger: 'change' }
```

I have tried using pattern but nothing worked, so what do i need to do, maybe a custom validation, maybe i m using regex wrong

Answer (score 0):

please look the link where i can not add any characters 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number

Comment: I have a constraint about that, i also need an error saying i need to use only numbers

Comment: better to use placeholder where user can read. ow write a function where you can check type of input and display error message

Comment: Are you using el-input or el-input-number?